# How can I sell INTEL covered calls?

Tags: united-kingdom, covered-call, call-options

As shown in this picture, how do I execute the strategy highlighted in yellow? I am based in the UK.
[image]

Source: http://seekingalpha.com/article/274231-intel-dividend-champion-in-the-making (10/6/11)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Options look like this (I clipped to show just these two).

[image: Intel Options]

You call the broker, and buy 100 shares of INTC for $2,132 and then ask to "Sell to Open" one contract of the September $23 call for $41, which is what it trades at this minute. If Intel goes to $30, That guy you sold the $41 valued option now has $700 for his money, and you just sold the stock for $2300, instead of $3000. 
Selling covered calls for these small amounts is no way to get rich.

Comment: Just curious - what does that scenario look like now that INTC is closer to $20? And what was the advice in the question trying to recommend, anyway?

Comment: The $23 strikes are worthless, no bid, 1 cent ask. Following the above trades, the buyer owns Intel at $2132 - $43 or $2089 for 100 shares. No great deal either way. The OP read an article suggesting selling covered calls to make more money than just buying the stock.